# How to make a textBox accept only Numbers and just one decimal point in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows 8 phone. I am writing a calculator app that can only accept numbers in the textbox and just a single decimal point. how do I prevent users from inputting two or more decimal Points in the text box as the calculator cant handle that.

I have been using Keydown Event, is that the best or should I use Key up?

```
private void textbox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) {

}
```

Comment: You need to do a lot more than handle key presses, like validate clipboard actions, deletions, negative numbers etc.

Comment: I used set the input scope to Numbers and it seem to take care of numbers and negative numbers. Thanks a lot

Comment: Too bad, can't downvote **all** wrong answers, it's just too costly, reputation-wise. Hence a comment up front: Do not attempt to validate input in a `KeyPress` event handler. This will break, as soon as a user decides to **paste** text. The `TextChanged` event is the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. I finally did this and it worked very well in the Text changed event. That was after setting the inputscope to Numbers

```
string dika = Textbox1.Text;
    int countDot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dika.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dika[i] == '.')
        {
            countDot++;
            if (countDot > 1)
            {
                dika = dika.Remove(i, 1); 
                i--;
                countDot--;
            }
        }
    }
Textbox1.Text = dika;
Textbox1.Select(dika.Text.Length, 0);
```

Comment: Now change the keyboard to DE or PL (you might need to install it first) and suffer.

Answer (score 5):

*You can use this for KeyPress Event
 set keypress event for your textbox in form.Designer like this*

```
this.yourtextbox.KeyPress +=new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(yourtextbox_KeyPress);
```

*then use it in your form*

```
//only number And single decimal point input فقط عدد و یک ممیز میتوان نوشت
        public void onlynumwithsinglepoint(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == '.'))
            { e.Handled = true; }
            TextBox txtDecimal = sender as TextBox;
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtDecimal.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

*then*

```
private void yourtextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            onlynumwithsinglepoint(sender, e);
        }
```

Comment: Won't work when text is pasted, for example. Not a solution. -1.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use RegExp with `TextChanged` event:
The snippet below will handle any integer and float number, both positive and negative

```
    string previousInput = "";
    private void InputTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex("^-{0,1}\d+\.{0,1}\d*$"); // This is the main part, can be altered to match any desired form or limitations
        Match m = r.Match(InputTextbox.Text);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            previousInput = InputTextbox.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            InputTextbox.Text = previousInput;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually solved the problem of having just numbers by making the inputscope to be Numbers. The major challenge now is to allow only one decimal point into the text box

Comment: this method can also be used to check for only one decimal point. Regex is very powerful tool for validation, text parsing.

Comment: What happen when cursor point not in the end of text box? Cursor will jump to end of text box .... So, will good to save previousSelectionStart and previousSelectionLength additional to previousInput for avoid cursor jump in case cursor not in the end of input.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use this extensively back in the .NET 2 days, not sure if it still works. Supports configurable precision, currency, negative numbers and handles all methods of input.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        private bool _AllowNegatives = true;
        private int _Precision = 0;
        private char _CurrencyChar = (char)0;
        private bool _AutoFormat = true;
        private decimal _MinValue = Decimal.MinValue;
        private decimal _MaxValue = Decimal.MaxValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if the negative values are allowed.
        /// </summary>
        [DefaultValue(true), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All), Description("Indicates if the negative values are allowed."), Category("Behavior")]
        public bool AllowNegatives
        {
            get
            {
                return this._AllowNegatives;
            }
            set
            {
                this._AllowNegatives = value;

                if (!value)
                {
                    if (this._MinValue < 0) this._MinValue = 0;
                    if (this._MaxValue < 1) this._MaxValue = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates the maximum number of digits allowed after a decimal point.
        /// </summary>
        [DefaultValue(0), Description("Indicates the maximum number of digits allowed after a decimal point."), Category("Behavior")]
        public int Precision
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Precision;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Precision", value.ToString(), "The value of precision must be an integer greater than or equal to 0.");
                }
                else
                {
                    this._Precision = value;
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the character to use as a currency symbol when validating input.
        /// </summary>
        [DefaultValue((char)0), Description("Gets or sets the character to use as a currency symbol when validating input."), Category("Behavior")]
        public char CurrencyChar
        {
            get
            {
                return this._CurrencyChar;
            }
            set
            {
                this._CurrencyChar = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if the text in the textbox is automatically formatted. Missing currency symbols and trailing spaces are added where applicable.
        /// </summary>
        [DefaultValue(true), Description("Indicates if the text in the textbox is automatically formatted. Missing currency symbols and trailing spaces are added where applicable."), Category("Behavior")]
        public bool AutoFormat
        {
            get
            {
                return this._AutoFormat;
            }
            set
            {
                this._AutoFormat = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the numerical value of the textbox.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Gets or sets the numerical value of the textbox."), Category("Data")]
        public decimal Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    return (decimal)0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return decimal.Parse(this.Text.Replace(this.CurrencyChar.ToString(), ""));
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0 && !this.AllowNegatives)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The specified decimal is invalid, negative values are not permitted.");
                }

                this.Text = this.FormatText(value.ToString());
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the maximum numerical value of the textbox.
        /// </summary>
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All), Description("Gets or sets the maximum numerical value of the textbox."), Category("Behavior")]
        public decimal MaxValue
        {
            get
            {
                    return this._MaxValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value <= this._MinValue)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The Maximum value must be greater than the minimum value.", "MaxValue");
                }
                else
                {
                    this._MaxValue = Decimal.Round(value, this.Precision);
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the minimum numerical value of the textbox.
        /// </summary>
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All), Description("Gets or sets the minimum numerical value of the textbox."), Category("Behavior")]
        public decimal MinValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this._MinValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0 && !this.AllowNegatives)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The Minimum value cannot be negative when AllowNegatives is set to false.", "MinValue");
                }
                else if (value >= this._MaxValue)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The Minimum value must be less than the Maximum value.", "MinValue");
                }
                else
                {
                    this._MinValue = Decimal.Round(value, this.Precision);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of the NumericTextBox class with the specified container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">The container of the control.</param>
        public NumericTextBox(System.ComponentModel.IContainer container)
        {
            ///
            /// Required for Windows.Forms Class Composition Designer support
            ///
            container.Add(this);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of the NumericTextBox class.
        /// </summary>
        public NumericTextBox()
        {
            ///
            /// Required for Windows.Forms Class Composition Designer support
            ///
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // 
            // NumericTextBox
            // 
            this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.NumericTextBox_KeyPress);
            this.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.NumericTextBox_Validating);

        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks to see if the specified text is valid for the properties selected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text to test.</param>
        /// <returns>A boolean value indicating if the specified text is valid.</returns>
        protected bool IsValid(string text)
        {
            Regex check = new Regex("^" + ((this.AllowNegatives && this.MinValue < 0) ? (@"\-?") : "") + ((this.CurrencyChar != (char)0) ? (@"(" + Regex.Escape(this.CurrencyChar.ToString()) + ")?") : "") + @"\d*" + ((this.Precision > 0) ? (@"(\.\d{0," + this.Precision.ToString() + "})?") : "") + "$");

            if (!check.IsMatch(text)) return false;
            if (text == "-" || text == this.CurrencyChar.ToString() || text == "-" + this.CurrencyChar.ToString()) return true;

            Decimal val = Decimal.Parse(text);

            if (val < this.MinValue) return false;
            if (val > this.MaxValue) return false;

            return true;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Formats the specified text into the configured number format.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text to format.</param>
        /// <returns>The correctly formatted text.</returns>
        protected string FormatText(string text)
        {
            string format = "{0:" + this.CurrencyChar.ToString() + "0" + ((this.Precision > 0) ? "." + new String(Convert.ToChar("0"), this.Precision) : "") + ";-" + this.CurrencyChar.ToString() + "0" + ((this.Precision > 0) ? "." + new String(Convert.ToChar("0"), this.Precision) : "") + "; £0" + ((this.Precision > 0) ? "." + new String(Convert.ToChar("0"), this.Precision) : "") + "}";
            return String.Format(format, text).Trim();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Overrides message handler in order to pre-process and validate pasted data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="m">Message</param>
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case 0x0302:
                    if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                    {
                        string paste = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
                        string text = this.Text.Substring(0, this.SelectionStart) + paste + this.Text.Substring(this.SelectionStart + this.SelectionLength);

                        if (this.IsValid(text))
                        {
                            base.WndProc(ref m);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if(components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        private void NumericTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || 
                (this.AllowNegatives && e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar("-")) || 
                (this.Precision > 0 && e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(".")) || 
                e.KeyChar == this.CurrencyChar)
            {
                string text = this.Text.Substring(0, this.SelectionStart) + e.KeyChar.ToString() + this.Text.Substring(this.SelectionStart + this.SelectionLength);
                if (!this.IsValid(text))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            else if (!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        private void NumericTextBox_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                this.Text = this.FormatText("0");
            }
            else if (this.IsValid(this.Text))
            {
                this.Text = this.FormatText(this.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply simple

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;
        decimal x;
        if (ch == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (!char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != '.' || !Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text+ch, out x) )
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void txtBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '\b')
        {
            // Allow Digits and BackSpace char
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && !((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains('.'))
        {
            //Allows only one Dot Char
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Validation required list**

- Stop more than one dot Char
- Stop first char as a dot input
- Stop allow other than digit and control

**Keypress event**

```
private void txtEstimate_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtEstimate.Text.Contains("."))
    {
        // Stop more than one dot Char
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtEstimate.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        // Stop first char as a dot input
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        // Stop allow other than digit and control
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

below input validation

- 0.1 - Valid
- .1 - Invalid
- 12..1 - Invalid
- 12.36 - Valid
- 123.2548 - Valid

Comment: works, but there's an error when I paste something with control + v, letters are still added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numeric Text box or

try this

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '\b')
 {
  e.Handled = false;
 }
 else
 {
    e.Handled = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: +1 for remembering the backspace, but you also should consider cut-copy-paste shortcuts

Comment: Ya Seph ... he has to stop cut,copy paste thanks for remaining me . :)

Comment: This approach also does not cosider entering several decimal points validation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help and answers. How do I stop copy and paste. I used input scope=Number and it seem to stop all copy and paste action

Comment: Make a chek for Control Key ... if user press control then make action as false ...

Answer (score 0):

For number ==> `ImputScope ="Number"`
And you can count character point in string like dat with a parsing for exemple :

```
char[] c = yourstring.tocharArray();
int i = 0;
foreach var char in c
if(char.equals(".") or char.equals(",")
i++

if (i > 1)
MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number")
```

This code is just for example but it's work.

Comment: Do I have to do this in a keydown event, I tried it out but there were many erros which i could not resolve

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtDecimal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b' && e.KeyChar!='.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtDecimal.Text.Contains("."))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this. this work for me.

```
 private void txtParciales_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtParciales.Text, @"\d+(\.\d{2,2})"))
                e.Handled = true;
            else e.Handled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I used.

```
 private void txtBoxBA_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // only allow 0-9 and "."
        e.Handled = !((e.Key.GetHashCode() >= 48 && e.Key.GetHashCode() <= 57));

        // check if "." is already there in box.
        if (e.Key.GetHashCode() == 190)
            e.Handled = (sender as TextBox).Text.Contains(".");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` controller

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgx" 
ValidationExpression="[0-9]*\.?[0-9]" ControlToValidate="YourTextBox" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Decimals only!!" Display="Dynamic"  ValidationGroup="lnkSave"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar != Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) && e.KeyChar != Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) && e.KeyChar != Convert.ToChar(Keys.Delete) && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != '1' && e.KeyChar != '2' && e.KeyChar != '3' && e.KeyChar != '4' && e.KeyChar != '5' && e.KeyChar != '6' && e.KeyChar != '7' && e.KeyChar != '8' && e.KeyChar != '9' && e.KeyChar != '0')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please describe what your code does so the asker can have a better understanding of how he should apply your solution

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with KeyPress

```
  private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.' 
            && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back) 
            || (e.KeyChar == '.' && textBox1.Text.Contains('.')))
        {                              
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```