# How to make a xaml textbox in silverlight accept only numbers with maximum one decimal point precision

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

How to make a xaml textbox in silverlight accept only numbers with maximum one decimal point precison. I have tried the answers in this question [How to make a textBox accept only Numbers and just one decimal point in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761487/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-numbers-and-just-one-decimal-point-in-windows). But it did not work. How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you put your xaml and cs page stuff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like this,

```
 txtDiscount.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(EnsureNumbers);
```

//Method to allow only numbers,

```
void EnsureNumbers(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            return; 
        }
        bool result =  EnsureDecimalPlaces();
        if (result == false)
        {
            var thisKeyStr = "";
            if (e.PlatformKeyCode == 190 || e.PlatformKeyCode == 110)
            {
                thisKeyStr = ".";
            }
            else
            {
                thisKeyStr = e.Key.ToString().Replace("D", "").Replace("NumPad", "");
            }
            var s = (sender as TextBox).Text + thisKeyStr;
            var rStr = "^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$";
            var r = new Regex(rStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            e.Handled = !r.IsMatch(s);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Method to ensure only 1 decimal,

```
  bool EnsureDecimalPlaces()
    {

        string inText = txtDiscount.Text;
        int decPointIndex = inText.IndexOf('.');
        if (decPointIndex < 1 || decPointIndex == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: how can i use this function for multiple text boxes. Is there any way ?

Comment: call the function in the textchanged event of those boxes

Comment: so i need to set variable intext to ((Textbox)sender).Text ?

Comment: this function is accepting alphabets also.. how to remove that and after  inputting the first number after the decimal point if i try to insert another number the number is appending to the number before decimal point. I need nothing to be entered in the textbox after the first decimal precision. How to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85485/discussion-between-geo-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: keypress is not available in silverlight