# Calculator keypress handle

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a calculator project and I have run into two problems.
The first problem is how to handle the keypress event so that numbers plus (+-/*.) all work however every other key is blocked. Heres the code im using at the moment:

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I know I could add each symbol separately by using `&& (e.KeyChar != '+') && (e.KeyChar != '-')` but is there an easier more efficient way of handle all of these keys?

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention that my calculator uses a text box so that is why I need to block the use of letters and some symbols

My second question is how can I stop the user being able to write two or more decimal points in one number for example 9.5.6 or 0.3.2.9?

Thanks

Comment: This can be solved by a StateMachine. Have a look at https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless

Comment: Depending on what event you're handling, just checking for the key you want should ensure no other keys trigger the event. E.g. `if (e.KeyChar == '+') { } else if (e.KeyChar == '-') { }` .

Comment: As for the second question, a messy solution would be to keep a global boolean (e.g. isDecimalEntered) and handle the textbox textchanged event, updating the boolean every time. A better solution would just be to use Decimal.TryParse() in the textchanged handler. For Reference: [Decimal.TryParse Method (String, Decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `switch(e.KeyChar)`?

Comment: I am using a text changed event and I tried the boolean method which you said however this meant you could not enter a decimal in the second number input for example 1.2+4.5 the second decimal was blocked.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thanks ill try that now

Comment: Just make a list of allowed Keys, not characters that your calculator KeyDown event will handle. Oh and don't use textbox. Preferably just keep the focus in the window and handle the keydown in the window level, just forward the key events to your viewmodel (if it is wpf).

Comment: I would suggest, editing your second question out and creating a new one specificly for that problem. That makes it easier to create a useful answer for at least one of your problems. There might be some people around, who could answer at least one of your problems, but won't, because they have no complete answer for your second problem

Comment: And your second problem might already be addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761487/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-numbers-and-just-one-decimal-point-in-windows

Comment: @JanneMatikainen The reason im using a textbox is because this is a project which has been set by a teacher. The teacher wanted to make it more challenging and include the use of an array by using the text box. Thanks

Comment: @Marco Ok thanks and sorry for that im new here :)

Comment: You should then also ask your teacher if you run into problems, that is why they are there. To help and guide you, one could say to teach you.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Its a project which is being assessed so I cant get help from the teacher

Answer (score 0):

Declare char array on class level:

```
private char[] allowed = new char[]
{
    '/','*','+','-'
};
```

On keypress event:

```
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !allowed.Contains(e.KeyChar) )
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```